# Concurrency & exceptions

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I wonder if can exists situation when **multiply exceptions can be thrown from the different threads simultaneously**.
If it is so, **how to handle them** properly in order to recover application and continue it`s execution?

Thanks for answers.
Good examples are welcomed.

Comment: handle each exception in each thread's run() method differentiatly

Comment: @Spring.Rush  - good examples are still welcomed )

Comment: multiple threads can do many things simultaneously like throw and handle multiple exceptions.  Can you give an example of where order they occur matters?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey  I can`t give an example due to I consider the situation when order of threads execution matters as bad implementation, because according to the specification of java virtual machine different realizations can provide different behavior

Comment: @spin_eight So I think you have answered your own question.  It should never matter if you use threads correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wonder if can exists situation when multiply exceptions can be thrown from the different threads simultaneously.

Yes, it is possible.

> If it is so, how to handle them properly in order to recover application and continue it`s execution?

`catch` blocks happen in the thread in which the exception was thrown, so each thread can do its own cleanup.

If a `catch` block needs to deal with an object that is referenced from multiple threads, then you need to be careful to lock properly just as if that object were accessible by multiple threads that were not processing an exception.

If you have installed a custom [`UncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) then you need to synchronize in that handler whenever it deals with mutable state so that it doesn't run into concurrency problems when invoked from multiple threads concurrently.

---

> What if catch block is in method from which threads are started?

In

```
Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    throw new NullPointerException();
  }
});
th.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
  public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {
    // This gets run because the NPE ends the child thread.
    System.err.println("Uncaught " + throwable);
  } 
});
try {
  th.start();
} catch (NullPointerException ex) {
  System.err.println("Not reached");
}
```

the catch block in the parent stack frame is not reached when the child thread throws an exception.

This happens because starting a thread is not like forking a process.  When forking a process the child process gets a copy of the parent process's stack, but when starting a thread, the child starts with its own empty stack.

Comment: what if catch block is in method from which threads are started?

Comment: @spin_eight, Child threads do not inherit the parent thread stack, so exceptions thrown by the child will not reach `catch` blocks in the parent.

Comment: thank you very much, I should read about exceptions mechanism in depth.

Comment: @spin_eight, You're welcome.  I added an edit about the differences between starting a thread and forking a process which might help.  Once you understand stack-unwinding the rest is easy.

Answer (score 1):

If multiple threads rely on one resource in order to work and that one resource has an error, then the threads that use that resource would all throw an exception. How you want to handle this is up to you, but I recommend that each thread handels it's own exception unless you have another thread that manages those threads and handels exceptions for them.

For example, in a game I made last summer, my sound system had many channels, each its own thread, and one thread that managed loading and adding sound data to a channel. I originally used Clip objects for each thread which would sometimes cause an error if too many clips were trying to play the same sound. I added a flag to each channel to tell if an exeption had been thrown in a channel. If my sound manager found a channel with an error while trying to add sound, it would remove that channel, add a new channel in its place, and give the string to the channel to refference sound bytes loaded in memory. 
There were other issues with many threads using the Clip interface at the same time. On seldom occation, the entire virtual machine would fail due to "not supporting mini dump". Since a catch clause can't stop virtual machine error, I switched to a different method of sound effect playing: SourceDataLine. I didn't have problems with that.

There are many more possible errors with running many threads. There are just as many ways to handle those errors.

Comment: thank you for interesting examples and also for solution with flag. Now I see what situation with multiply simultanious exception is not so rare as I initially considered it. As far as i remember volatile modificator for such flag should be used?

Comment: I'm not sure what the volatile modifier does. I use synchronized methods to get and set data. Here's what my sound manager uses to check for errors:    boolean ok=true;   public synchronized void setStatus(boolean status){this.ok=status;}   public synchronized boolean getStatus(){return this.ok;}     What the synchronized modifier does is it adds a lock for objects or functions. A thread must aquire this lock to use an object, wait if another thread has the lock for an object it wants, and release the lock on the object when the thread is done using it.